# How does KVM set its own netfilter rules?

Tags: networking, centos, firewall, kvm

I've been poking around with KVM VM's on Centos 6.4 not having an internet connection on my VM's, I found something curious:

Upon booting the machine, iptables has rules in the FORWARD chain to allow traffic through to the VM's and all is well. When I run `service iptables restart`, however, it looks like it pulls the config rules from `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` (default settings which reject all forwarding) and thus, I've been relegated to either dropping the firewall completely on the physical host or rebooting to get the FORWARD rules added so it works again.

**Edit:**
Indeed, I could just modify the firewall rules myself to allow it, but isn't the focus of this question. I'm more focused on the following question #1:

**My questions are:**

1. At what point (or by what mechanism) are these FORWARD rules added in?
2. How can I recover the FORWARD rules without rebooting the machine?

Quite frankly, I'm not even sure where to start searching for this issue. I found [this page](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=0CJEBEBYwCQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.godshell.com%2Fblog%2Farchives%2F283-Hey-KVM%2C-youve-got-your-bridge-in-my-netfilter....html&ei=wchpUpaSNeXwyAGJ2IGYCg&usg=AFQjCNFUsYR-bGXKEBki0w2T56Zc4dSiOw&sig2=oKGbTnLqNp0iZom-_f1GdQ&bvm=bv.55123115,d.aWc&cad=rja) that says to modify `/etc/sysctl.conf` with the following variables which allegedly make netfilter ignore traffic to bridged connections:

```
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
```

The problem with that is that my `sysctl.conf` is already set as such and netfilter still does its thing, happily blocking everything to the VM's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KVM itself doesn't do anything but run the VM. iptables rules are put in place by libvirt, (or the qemu-ifup scripts if you are doing things hardcore and manual)

In any case, if you want to avoid the iptables complication, don't use VMs in a NAT config, and switch to using a bridge or OVS instead.

[OVS config](http://git.openvswitch.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=openvswitch;a=blob_plain;f=INSTALL.KVM;hb=HEAD)

[Bridged networking](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-linux-kvm-virtualization-bridged-networking-with-libvirt/)

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I ran `service libvirtd restart` and the FORWARD rules I was looking for appeared again.

Comment: Yup, you have to understand the stack - there's qemu-kvm at the bottom in the kernel, libvirt on top of that to manage the VMs and the way they operate, and whatever management/cloud solution (like oVirt or openstack) on top of that to pass user commands to libvirt, which will run VMs accordingly by orchestrating KVM